# Java signing data with only a public key (OpenSAML)

Tags: java, encryption, saml, opensaml

So we were provided with a public X509 Certificate which I need to use to sign a SAML Assertion

Here is what I currently have:

```
        BasicX509Credential credential = new BasicX509Credential();
        credential.setEntityCertificate(getPublicCertificate());
        credential.setPrivateKey(null);

        // SIGNING
        SecurityConfiguration config = Configuration.getGlobalSecurityConfiguration();
        Signature signature = (Signature) Configuration.getBuilderFactory().getBuilder(Signature.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME).buildObject(Signature.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
        signature.setSignatureAlgorithm(SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA256);
        signature.setSigningCredential(credential);
        SecurityHelper.prepareSignatureParams(signature, credential, config, null);
        assertion.setSignature(signature);
        // END SIGNING

        AssertionMarshaller marshaller = new AssertionMarshaller();
        Element plaintextElement = marshaller.marshall(assertion);

        Signer.signObject(signature);
```

However, when `Signer.signObject(signature)` gets called, it is throwing a `NullPointerException` because there is no privateKey in the credential object. Since we were provided with the X509 Certificate, we obviously only have access to the public key. What should the private key be set to? Thanks!

Comment: You must have your own private key.

Answer (score 0):

You require the private key for signing. Signature generation always requires the private key, verification a trusted public key (of the party that did the signing).

So maybe there is a method you can call besides `getPublicCertificate` or maybe the private key is delivered otherwise.

Generating the private key out of the public key is of course not possible; there would be little use of private keys if that was possible, and they would not be very private.